# It's possible change TabHost color when click tab

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I can't change yellow color to blue,how to change?

[image]

Comment: How ? When you click tab,tab lights yellow color! I want to use blue color instead of orange color!

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/

Comment: Yeah! I used to this tutorial

Comment: and I want to remove orange color when clicked...

Answer (score 0):

Hi I also gone through the same problem. I solved it by using the code as below
try you may get some hint.

```
  tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

    public void onTabChanged(String yourArghere) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tab.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
            tab.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.color.YourColorhere);
        }
        tab.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tab.getCurrentTab())
                .setBackgroundResource(R.color.yourColor);

    }
});
```

Comment: When you pressed tab button, tab lights orange,when you selected tab lights  grey,not selected lights black. I want to remove orange color. When you pressed tab,tab lights orange then background color changed to grey

Comment: Why can'nt you try this link   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240756/android-how-to-remove-selected-tab-highlight-color-on-press-highlight-on-tabw

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.you need to create selector drawable inside drawable folder like this
pass these drawable to Activities.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<!--  WHEN SELECTED -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/img_menu_cal_sel" android:state_selected="true"/>
<!--  WHEN NOT SELECTED -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/img_menu_cal" android:state_selected="false" />
</selector>
```

Comment: When you pressed tab button tab lights orange,when selected tab color grey,not selected black. I want to remove orange color. When you pressed tab,tab lights orange then background color changed to grey